# "in more details" or "in detail"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is correct to cite:

> To discuss this in more details.

or

> To discuss this in detail.

Answer (score 17):

Neither is exactly correct...  I think the phrase you are looking for is "To discuss this in more detail"  (no "s" on "detail") which you would use with a qualifying or defining phrase. Examples: "Please call me so we can discuss this project in more detail" or "To discuss this in more detail, you can contact me at blahblahwhatever."

"in detail" describes the level of specificity and means that you are explaining the fine or small but important parts or provide complete information or descriptions - as in you will provide more information or specifics and "more" or  tells them you are either going to provide more specific information than whatever "this" is in your question.

**Examples**:

- A more detailed explanation of the word "detail" is included below.

OR

- I will describe the various meanings of the word "detail" in detail below or if you think this explanation has already been detailed, I will discuss it in MORE detail below. Another answer might be less detailed, but get to the point faster.

---

To use the correct adjective with the phrase "in detail", think about fewer vs less in number vs amount - but remember "in detail" means specifically or completely already.

Examples:

- I have read your question and answered it "in detail".
- If you want to read my explanations "in more detail", keep reading.
- You might find another answer that explains it just as well with fewer details (which would mean an explanation with less specifics/examples), but describing it in less detail might not provide a total understanding of the word. (Here, less/greater describes a comparative quality rather than quantity)

in less detail or in more detail  -Correct

- however when describing the quantity you would use detail or details I will add additional facts and examples and so it can be said I will give "more details" below.
- There is a shorter answer with "fewer details" describing various uses of detail "in less detail" somewhere else, I'm sure.

---

"Details" vs "Detail" without getting too far into grammatical rules,

A "Detail" (used as a noun) is an individual feature or characteristic and therefore, the plural "details" is used when you are talking about multiple individual features/characteristics.

However, when using "detail" to describe the level of specificity/completeness you use the phrase "in detail".  See the above examples on modifying the phrase in more detail,  I will add more details about the definitions and usage below and provide more details.

Detail defined as a NOUN
When used this way, it can have countable items:
An Example:

> The "details" of this site include:
>
> 1. A forum for questions
> 2. A system to vote for the best answers
> 3. etc.

or uncountable items that

I can also mean small/specific things that you only see with closer examination.

- The detail of his paintings illustrate the smallest details of the subject matter and make it photo-real.
- His drawing lacks detail and looks rushed because he did not add enough detail around the eyes and the details there really matter.
- Those are the details that make someone recognizable.
- I wonder if he could add more detail if I looked up his details (meaning specific info about him) and emailed him my opinion, in detail.

Detail can also be used to mean a small, unimportant item
An Example: The font of the page numbers is just a detail, it is the content on the page that is important.
Again, the plural form is "details".
Example:

> The details such as the
>
> 1. page number font
> 2. number of lines that make up the border of boxes
> 3. [Insert irrelevant or unimportant fact/characteristic/item here]
>    are not important in web design, so do not spend a lot of time worrying
>    about them.

Detail can also be a verb meaning to tell specifically or explain completely or minutely:

Example:

> Please detail the important parts of the site.

In response, a person could list and completely describe the features/items/facts he or she considers important.

The meaning of the phrase "in detail" is similar to the definition of the adjective "detailed", used to mean a very specific/complete way.
Example:

> "The features of the car are listed "in detail" on the next page."

is very similar to

> "A detailed list of features for this car is located on the next page."

You could also say:

> "Go to the next page to see the details of each feature on this car."

All mean that the features of the car will be described independently and explained completely.

"in details" is not used as a phrase.

Comment: It is the worst answer I have ever seen.